# Goのairの環境構築でDockerを使った場合、airが機能しない件について

Tags: windows, docker, go

### PCの環境

使用OS:Windows11
Docker:Docker Desktop for Windows

### 実施したこと

1.以下のDockerfileを使用

```
FROM golang:1.18

ENV TZ /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Tokyo

ENV ROOT=/go/src/app
WORKDIR ${ROOT}


ENV GO111MODULE=on

COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080

RUN go install github.com/cosmtrek/air@latest
CMD ["air"]
```

2.ターミナルのログ
[image: ターミナルのログ]

起動はしてるようだが、ここでGoのファイルに変更を加えてもホットリロードされない

誰か原因がわかる有識者の方、解決法をご教示いただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 起きていること

「Goのair」は、ソースコードを変更したときに自動でそれを検知し、アプリケーション（ここでは[Echo](https://github.com/labstack/echo) ）を再起動するツールです。
[GitHub - cosmtrek/air: ☁️ Live reload for Go apps](https://github.com/cosmtrek/air)

いっぽう、Dockerはソースコードからイメージをビルドし、同じ状態から起動・実行できるのを特徴としています。

記載されているDockerfile の中で、 `COPY . .` としている行のタイミングで現在のソースコードをDockerイメージにコピーし、Dockerコンテナはこのコードで実行されています。
このため、手元でコードを編集しても、Docker内部のairはそれを検知できず、結果ホットリロードされない、という形になっています。

## 解決方法

コンテナを使わないか、開発環境ディレクトリをマウントするかの2種類の方法が考えられます。